# Loop around node in state diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a feeling this should be simple, but I can't find how to do it. I'm trying to draw an arrow looping around the corner of a node in a state diagram. I have the following, but as you see it cuts the corner, plus ideally the arrow would loop from nearer the corner.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%node distance = 15mm and 300mm,
    node/.style={
        draw,
        rectangle,
        text width=25mm,
        text centered,
        minimum height=20mm
    },  
    arrow/.style={
        very thick,
        ->
    }]

\node[node] (state) {State};

\draw [arrow] (state.south)  to [out=270, in=0]  (state.east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Something like `\node [draw] {a} edge [in=-10,out=-55,loop] ();` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have several possibilities: you can use the `.. controls ..` syntax, or the `out=<value>,in=<value>,loop` options perhaps combined with an appropriate `looseness`, or (as **Jake** suggested) you can use  and `arc` to get a proper circle arc:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%node distance = 15mm and 300mm,
    node/.style={
        draw,
        rectangle,
        text width=25mm,
        text centered,
        minimum height=20mm
    },  
    arrow/.style={
        very thick,
        ->
    }]

\node[node] (state) {State};

\draw[red] [arrow] (state.270) .. controls  (0.5,-3) and (3.5,-1) ..  (state.0);
\draw[blue] (state) edge [out=270,in=0,loop] (state);
\draw[green] (state) edge [out=270,in=0,loop,looseness=4] (state);
\draw [arrow] (state.south east) ++(-0.75cm,0pt) arc [start angle=-180, end angle=90, radius=0.75cm];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great thanks, still new to tikz but I'm starting to see how it all works now...